# Counting characters in a popup textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup, modalpopupextender

What I need to do is give one of those character counters to let users know how many characters they can enter into a textbox.

The trick, apparently, is that the textbox is on a popup box.

I tried implementing the code found [here](http://rosshawkins.net/archive/2006/12/04/asp.net-text-counter.html.aspx), but it doesn't seem to be working.  No errors or anything, it's just that the number of characters left never changes and I can type well past the supposed limit.

What I have is this:

```
<!--//**********************************
    // Comment Character Count
    //**********************************  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
     if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
     else
        countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
     }
 </script>
```

And then down in my code body I have this:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" Height="190px" BackColor="#0f6fc6" ScrollBars="Auto">
        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowLines="true" PopulateNodesFromClient="false" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_PopupCommentsBox" Height="118px" ShowExpandCollapse="true" Font-Size="X-Small" Width="295px" NodeIndent="10" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" ExpandDepth="0"></asp:TreeView>   
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTreeselect" runat="server" Enabled="False" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox></asp:Panel>
<!--  ************************************  -->
            <asp:modalpopupextender id="MdlCommentsExtender" runat="server"     
                targetcontrolid="TreeView1" popupcontrolid="pnlComments" 
                popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="True" 
                backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG" Enabled="False"  >
            </asp:modalpopupextender>

            <asp:panel id="pnlComments" style="display: none" runat="server" BackColor="White" CssClass="modalPopup">
                <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
                    <div class="PopupHeader" id="Div3" style="border: thin solid #000000; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; background-color: #C0C0C0; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; height: 40px;" ><br />Pend Comment</div>
                        <div class="PopupBody" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
                            <table style="width: 300px">
                                <tr style="text-align:left">
                                    <td style="padding:4px"><asp:Label ID="lblCommentBox" runat="server" Text="Comment:"></asp:Label></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding:4px">
                                   <!--     <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBox_Old" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" TextMode="multiline" Wrap="True" Height="70px" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small"></asp:TextBox>  -->
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBox" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="textbox" Wrap="True" Height="70px" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" Rows="3" runat="server" onkeyup="textCounter(txtCommentBox, this.form.remLen, 50);" onkeydown="textCounter(txtCommentBox, this.form.remLen, 50);" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>  
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="remLen" name="remLen" size="2" maxlength="3" value="50" /> characters left
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Controls">
                            <table style="width: 300px">
                                <tr>
                                   <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center"> <asp:Button ID="mdlCmntsOk_Click" runat="server" Text="OK" CssClass="textbox" Height="28px" Width="75px" OnClick="mdlCommentsOk_Click" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </asp:panel>
<!--  ************************************  -->
```

Can anyone tell me what might be going wrong?  Is this not working because it's inside a modalpopupextender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the event attributes to this:

```
onkeyup="textCounter( this, this.form.remLen, 50);" 
onkeydown="textCounter( this, this.form.remLen, 50);"
```

You were using a variable name that had no value in that scope. `this` in an event attribute always refers to the owning node. If you had defined `txtCommentBox` globally in JavaScript (either in the head or document), then it would be useable there.

Comment: BRILLIANT!  Thanks a ton!

Comment: @JohnnyBones No problem.